# is laravel cloning my mock object?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-5, phpunit

Im testing a Soap web service with `getMockFromWsdl` from phpunit, for unit testing within laravel works fine, but when I try to replace the SoapClient in a feature test, it always fails, like the web service never called, but actually the mock is called.

I suspect that laravel is cloning somewhere my `$this->soapClient` because if I debug the code, it calls the soap mock and gets what is faked in the mock but always receive the error:

```
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:GetToken> when invoked at least once.
Expected invocation at least once but it never occurred.
```

My code is like:

```
public function test_soap_call()
{
    $this->soapClient = $this->getMockFromWsdl(dirname(__FILE__).'/../Mocks/service.wsdl');

    $this->soapClient->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
        ->method('GetToken')
        ->with(['Code' => '03600', 'User' => 'username'])
        ->willReturn(unserialize('O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:26:"GetTokenResult";s:36:"5aae60ec-2bcd-459d-a135-a20eb7c10007";}'));

    $this->app->instance('MySoapClient', $this->soapClient);

    $this->postJson('/api/order', $this->getValidRequest());

}
```

and in my controller (`/api/order`) I have

```
$soap = $this->app->make('MySoapClient');
$soap->GetToken(['Code' => '03600', 'User' => 'username']);
```

Am I using correctly the Laravel Service Container?

PD: Something similar happened to me, when doing a Spy and using `$app->instance`, where I was trying to get what was passed to an object, but always got null. I solved it declaring the field of the spy static.

Comment: I think i have solved the problem refactoring the dependency injection.
I am using a queue in the controller, and the laravel queues needs to serialize the pushed objects.

So I think the mocked object is not serialized properly, and building the soap client dependency in the execution time of the queue solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check this from php.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

... "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true. ...